# How to remove a substring from JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working with JavaScript for a project where I have been using a function like below for having a string output.

```
      function formatObject(obj){
       var obj;
       var s="";
     $.each(obj,function(k,v) { s = s+k+"="+v+"&"; });
     return s
        return JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/,/g,',\n__events__    ').replace('{','{\n    ').replace('}','\n}')
        
  }
```

And out put of `formatObject(obj)` having an extra

```
__events__=function () {}
```

I am confused how I should remove this unwanted keyword from my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skip it when you're building the string:

```
$.each(obj, function(k, v) { if (k != '__events__') s = s + k + '=' + v + '&'; });
```